# .NET Gitlab YAML Artifacts not found

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, yaml, gitlab-ci

I am trying to release a .net core 7 mvc application from gitlab. At the buld stage it gives the following error:

```
WARNING: /builds/xmoor/Xmoor-Payroll-Management/bin/Release/net7.0/: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory (/builds/xmoor/Xmoor-Payroll-Management)
```

I used the following script for building and making the release:

```
build:
  stage: build
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0
  script:
    - dotnet build $solution --configuration Release --no-restore
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/bin/Release/net7.0
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Some debugging may be needed first. Are any files actually generated in that path? Please add `before_script: ['ls -l $CI_PROJECT_DIR/bin/Release/net7.0']` and `after_script: ['ls -l $CI_PROJECT_DIR/bin/Release/net7.0']` and check the job log. Also, is your [Runner `config.toml` customizing](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnerscustom_build_dir-section) any related setting?

Comment: Also note the full message: `Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory`. `CI_PROJECT_DIR` resolves to an _absolute_ path, so removing that would be worth a try as well.